# Using the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, prove that $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$ and explain why

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, cauchy-riemann-equations

Using the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, prove that $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$ and explain why is it only holomorphic in that region.

In our course, $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ with upper-case L refers to the principal branch of log where $0\leq Arg(z)<2\pi$

---

**My attempt:**

$$\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$$

Let $r:=|z|=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ **and** let $\theta:=\operatorname{Arg}(z)=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$

And thus

$$\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln(r)+i\theta$$

Let $u=\ln(r)$ and $v=\theta$. For the C.R.Es to be satisfied:

$$u_x=v_y$$ and $$u_y=-v_x$$

must hold for some region.

$u_x=\frac{du}{dr}\frac{dr}{dx}$ $u_y=\frac{du}{dr}\frac{dr}{dy}$

$v_x=\frac{dv}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}$  $v_x=\frac{dv}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}$

$$u_x=\frac{1}{r}\frac{x}{r}=\frac{x}{r^2}$$
$$u_y=\frac{1}{r}\frac{y}{r}=\frac{y}{r^2}$$

$$v_x=\frac{-y}{r^2}$$  $$v_y=\frac{x}{r^2}$$

---

So for some region, $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ has partial derivatives that satisfy the C.R.Es. Meaning it is holomorphic in that region.

As for the reason behind the region. I feel it is related to $\arctan$ being continuous only in that region. Can someone explain this part? Also, graphically, where is this region?

Comment: And what is the "principal branch"  of log that you refer to?

Comment: As shown above, principal branch of log is the function Log(z):=ln|z|+iArg(z) where 0<=Arg(z)<=2pi. Other branches allow Arg(z) to be any value.

Comment: I ask because there are other choices possible. Also I think $\ 0\le \theta <2\pi\ $ is what you mean. This important information **should** appear in the body of the question. The $[0,\infty)$ should be clear.

Comment: @Somos I thought "principal branch of log" was a formal term. Sorry about that.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article [Principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) for one definition. Please **include** your definition of principal branch in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual definition of principal logarithm the argument is taken to be in $(-\pi, \pi]$. With this definition the correct domain of analyticity is $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. So the statement requires a modification.  [Of course if you redefine Log using argument of $(0,2\pi]$ then the statement is correct]. Your argument for the first part is correct. Hint for showing that Log is not continuous on the negative real axis: show that $\arg(-x+\frac 1 n) \to \pi$ and $\arg(-x-\frac 1 n)\to -\pi$ for any $x>0$.

Comment: This is not a homework question. This is a statement from lecture notes that has no explanation attached. Just give me the explanation please. Also, what does that region represent. Is it the lower-half complex plane?

Comment: The principal argument of a complex number lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$. For a point of the type $-x+\frac 1 n$ (which is approaching the negative real axis from above)  the argument is less than $\pi$ and it approaches $\pi$ as $ n \to \infty$.  But for a point of the type $-x-\frac 1 n$ (which is approaching the negative real axis from below  the argument is greater than $-\pi$ and it approaches $-\pi$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: Doesnt that mean it should be C\[0,-inf) not C\[0,inf)?

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa You are right. I have added some explanation to my answer now.

Comment: So should we now show that (x+$\frac{1}{n}$) approaches 0 as n approaches $\inf$ and that (x-$\frac{1}{n}$) approaches $2\pi$ as n approaches $\inf$? And what does that show? I havent had to deal with continuity problems in a while.

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa Exactly. That is the way to go.

Comment: But why does that show that it is not continuous on the positive Real axis?

Comment: Well, $x \pm \frac 1 n$ converges to $x$ doesn't it?. So continuiuty would require the arguments of both to converge to the same limit.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. This was not mentioned anytime during the lectures. He (the lecturer) just wrote the region where Log(z) isnt continuous (positive real axis) without explanation.I didnt know about the arguments converging.